# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding' using pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root',
    passwd='123456',db='home', charset="utf-8")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""create table job_list(job varchar(30) , people varchar(30) , catagory varchar(30)  , place varchar(30), publish varchar(30)) """)

try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT  INTO  job_list(job,people,catagory,place,publish) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
        ["算法工程师", "2018毕业生", "研发", "雅加达", "2018-03-28"])
    conn.commit()
except pymysql.Error as e:
    print(e)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

[having set charset but it is not useful,how can i  insert Chinese into mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpUL.png)

Comment: Please add the full backtrace that Python gives you. Also, please fix the formatting of the code, it's close to unreadable.

Comment: Does `charset="utf8"` work?

Comment: The `charset` is not the python encoding specifier but one cooked up by pymysql to map to encodings. You can find the full list at `https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/charset.py`

Comment: Its kinda lame that they don't catch the unknown charset and toss back a more sensible error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`charset` is a mysql database character set name that needs to be converted to a python encoding. `pymysql` has a large list of them in [charset.py](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/charset.py). Rather perversely, pymysql either spits back the charset name you passed in or raises the non-obvious error you see. In the `pymysql` world, "utf8" is a valid character set, but "utf-8" is not. So, just change your connect to

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root',
    passwd='123456',db='home', charset="utf8")
```