# optimize python code for quicker response

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

This code works, but is very slow. And I will like to use sqlalchemy module because the rest of the script uses that instead of mysql. Is there any advantage of using sqlalchemy or should I continue with this ...

```
for emp_id in mylist:
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='x.x.x.x', port='3306', database='xxx', user='root', password='xxx')

        cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
        sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT col1, col2, Photo from tbl where ProfileID = %s"""

        cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id, ))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in record:
            image =  row[2]
            file_name = 'myimages4'+'/'+str(row[0])+ '_' + str(row[1]) + '/' + 'simage' + str(emp_id) + '.jpg'
            write_file(image, file_name)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error :
        connection.rollback()
        print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if(connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to set up new mysql connection and obtain cursor on each iteration? If no, opening it once at the beginning will really speed up your code.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='x.x.x.x', port='3306', database='xxx', user='root', password='xxx', charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)

for emp_id in mylist:
    try:
        sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT col1, col2, Photo from tbl where ProfileID = %s"""

        cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id, ))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in record:
            image =  row[2]
            file_name = 'myimages4'+'/'+str(row[0])+ '_' + str(row[1]) + '/' + 'simage' + str(emp_id) + '.jpg'
            write_file(image, file_name)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error :
        connection.rollback()
        print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        # ouch ...
        if(connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

**UPD:**
Actually you don't even need to make N queries to database, because all data can be obtained in one query with `WHERE ProfileID IN (.., ..)` SQL statement. Take a look this small code, which solves a pretty much identical task:

```
transaction_ids = [c['transaction_id'] for c in checkouts]
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(transaction_ids))
dm_cursor.execute("SELECT ac_transaction_id, status FROM transactions_mapping WHERE ac_transaction_id IN (%s)" % format_strings, tuple(transaction_ids)) 
payments = dm_cursor.fetchall()
```

Please use it to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. But got this error... AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'charset'

Comment: Can u try to add `charset="utf8"` to connection params? I have updated code. [Sauce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828342/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-encoding-using-pymysql)

Comment: charset="utf-8" worked. But utf8 did not. Thanks for your help. Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: Okay, can u try `pymysql.connect(....)`, instead of `pymysql.connector.connect(...)`.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of ID's in the list. I will need to change "max_allowed_packet" variable for "IN" clause that is not possible.

Comment: `x * 10 000 ids * 8 byte (max 8 digit ASCII encoded number) + x * 9999 of ',' * 1 byte`, it's `x * 0.2 mb` (1 <= x <= 9). And I just checked that default value of `max_allowed_packet` 16 mb. So I don't think it's a limitation in ur case.